# Rails Haml form url parameter - how to make html form use the desired rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, forms

With the HAML code:

```
%form{:action => "activate_foobar", :method => :post, :controller => "foobar", :url => activate_foobar_foobar_index_path}
%input{:type => "submit", :value => "Activate"}
```

The submit button directs to

```
No route matches "/activate_foobar"
```

rather than to "/foobar/activate_foobar". It does not seem to understand the url parameter.

---

### **Details**

On the index page of foobar, there is a form which I'm trying to post to foobar_controller's method activate_foobar. Foobar does not have a model, as there is no such object - it is only a specialised property of Widget. (Widget has a model, and a method .activate_foobar)

activate_foobar_foobar_index is defined in routes as:

```
resources :foobar, :only => [:index] do
  collection do
    post :activate_foobar
  end
end
```

:confirmed with rake:routes to be:

```
activate_foobar_foobar_index POST     /foobar/activate_foobar(.:format)   {:action=>"activate_foobar", :controller=>"foobar"}
```

:as expected.

Furthermore, experimentation with a simple:

```
=link_to "Activate", activate_foobar_foobar_index_path, {:method => :post}
```

:routed successfully to /foobar/activate_foobar

Within the confines of using a form (and not using simple_form_for or other model based solutions), how do you correct the path "foobar/activate_foobar"?

Sources:
 I'm following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html "Adding more RESTful Actions" and http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp to try to understand how to direct a form to the right method of the right controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say it send the form to /activate_foobar, for some reason (maybe haml bug) it don't take the :controller param, to solve this in action write

```
:action => 'foobar/activate_foobar'
```

but you must be careful because it takes a relative route instead of absolute. So if you don't want to handle that issue I suggest you to change to rails form helper

```
= form_tag(activate_foobar_foobar_index_path, :method => :post) do
```

Comment: With or without the controller param, explicitly setting a relative route causes immediate logging out. Form_tag is just what I needed though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

since activate_foobar is nested under foobar did you try doing

```
 :url => activate_foobar_foobar_index_path(@foobar)
```

you need to tell rails where to look for the specific foobar to activate_foobar.

hope it helps.